# is not very polite of somebody

Tags: phrase-meaning

I saw the following staement in my grammar textbook and I wonder what’s the real meaning of “***That is not very polite of him***” in the statement?

> *Kevin never says 'thank you'. That isn't very polite of him.*

Does it mean that “He is not very polite.”? Or does it mean that "He is not usually that impolite"?

Comment: Neither. It means ***that specific action*** wasn't very polite (i.e. - it was ***impolite***). So your second interpretation is relatively "likely". In every other situation, Keven might actually be the most polite person you could ever hope to meet. It's just that he ***wasn't polite THEN***. The fact that Kevin did one specific thing that wasn't polite doesn't necessarily mean he's ***always*** impolite, or that being impolite is "in his nature".

Comment: But it's stated that "He never says 'thank you'". So, obviously he is always impolite.

Comment: If it's that obvious, why are you asking here? :) Seriously, I didn't read the text carefully, so I thought it was *Kevin never **said** thank you* (where ***never*** is used colloquially to mean ***didn't***, referring to ***a single occasion***). The fact that you've chosen an example where Kevin ***habitually*** fails to act politely simply confuses the issue here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means that this particular action (or in this case inaction) is not polite.  He may be polite in other ways.  You can use this phrase about a specific time

> Kevin didn't say thank you when he received his present. That wasn't very polite.

Or, as in your example, you can use it of a an act that is always or never done.

You might infer that since the speaker has made a point of mentioning "never says thank-you" that Kevin is usually more polite, or (since saying thank-you is about the most basic piece of politeness) that Kevin must be usually quite rude.

Answer (score 0):

It most probably means Kevin is a little rude because he never says "thank you".